# Xamarin studio folder structure issue in iOS project

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I am having trouble with xamarin folders. Currently I'm writing xamarin iOS project. In Xcode I used directories for  grouping images, there could be several levels of nested folders, but when I was building project for device or iOS simulator, these resources where simply being copied to main bundle, without any folder structure. I can't reach the same behaviour in xamarin studio. Whenever I create folders in my project and put pictures or other resources in them, this folder structure is recreated on the actual device, and thus, I struggle against different paths, when loading images. How can I make xamarin studio simply copy the files in the folders to main bundle, instead of recreating folder structure?

Thanks for help.

Comment: FWIW, Xcode's "Folders" aren't really folders, they are just file groupings and do not reflect on-disk file structure. Xamarin Studio does not support this concept of virtual file groupings and so using subfolders does not work quite the way you expect. However, using real folders in Xcode works the same as folders in Xamarin Studio.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My first suggestion is to change the `BuildAction` property of your images to `BundleResource`.

Once you do that, there are multiple ways of achieving your goal:

The first option is to specify a `LogicalName` to be whatever you want the name to be inside of the compiled app bundle. Currently there's no way to set the `Resource ID` (UI name for the LogicalName property) for anything other than `EmbeddedResource` files (I'll work on fixing that momentarily), but you can edit the *.csproj like so:

```
<BundleResource Include="Icons\icon.png">
  <LogicalName>icon.png</LogicalName>
</BundleResource>
```

Normally, that `Icons\icon.png` file would be copied into the iOS app bundle as `Icons/icon.png`, however, the LogicalName property overrides the relative path name. In this case it would be copied over as simply `icon.png`.

As another example, you can also do this:

```
<BundleResource Include="Icons\iOS\icon.png">
  <LogicalName>AppIcon.png</LogicalName>
</BundleResource>
```

This will copy the `Icons\iOS\icon.png` file into the root of the iOS app bundle and also rename it to `AppIcon.png`.

A second option is to simply move your image file(s) into the `Resources` folder. The Resources folder is special directory that get stripped out of the default path names when copied over to the iOS app bundle. In other words, `Resources\icon.png` would be copied over into the root of the iOS app bundle as `icon.png` rather than `Resources\icon.png` as is the case with normal project directories.

A third option is to simply register other "Resource" directories of your own (and they can exist within other directories, including the default Resources directory).

For example, you could have the structure in your project:

```
Resources/
   Icons/
      icon.png
      icon@2x.png
```

And in your *.csproj file, edit the following tag:

```
<IPhoneResourcePrefix>Resources</IPhoneResourcePrefix>
```

and replace it with:

```
<IPhoneResourcePrefix>Resources;Resources\Icons</IPhoneResourcePrefix>
```

This will ensure that the icon.png and icon@2x.png files are installed in the root of the iOS app bundle.

Comment: Sorry after you've edited the answer on Jun 19, I didn't notice your answer. almost 6 months had already passed since then :)) I've just seen this. really great answer! thanks!

Comment: Where is all of this documented BTW? I really miss the run script build phase from Xcode, and I'm looking for sane ways of doing various stuff during builds.

Comment: This is a great answer - and it's helped me cleanup my resources folder. Thanks!

Comment: You would need to have both combinations in your `< IPhoneResourcePrefix>` if you're working on both Xamarin Studio on Mac and VS on Windows:
`<IPhoneResourcePrefix>Resources;Resources/Icons;Resources\Icons</IPhoneResourcePrefix>`

Comment: You actually only need "Resources\Icons" (updated my answer) since Xamarin Studio will convert that into a Unix path on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin has two ways to setup files you want present in the iOS bundle:

1. Put them in any folder, and mark the "Build Action" as "Content". Whatever directory structure you have in your project will be present in the main bundle.
2. Put them in the "Resources" folder, with a "Build Action" as "BundleResource", this does the same as #1, but removes the "Resources" folder from the path present in the bundle. This is a nice place to put all images you want in the root of your bundle but would clutter up your project.

Comment: Yes but I if I put some folders inside resources folder, they are also copied to bundle. So only way is to just collect all images in one folder??? What a stupid thing.

Comment: I'm not following what you want. Are you wanting to have a folder structure in the project, but a flat structure in the bundle?

Comment: Yeah exactly! Like it is in Xcode. I use resource groups or folders their, but in any case the contents are copied in flat structure in bundle.

Comment: Use solution folders in Xamarin Studio. These are virtual folders that do not exist in the file system.

Comment: And how can I add solution folder? Only Thing available in context menu when right clicking project is New Folder, which adds and ordinary folder.

Comment: Solution folders only group projects, so I don't think @Krumelur's option will help you. There is a "logical" name or something on items set as BundleResource, I'll take a look today and see if you can remove subfolders.

Comment: Using the LogicalName property on BundleResource items should work for what he needs.